# Reverse "hg update --clean"

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Is the command described in the title reversible?

I tried searching the log (with hg log) and stripping the corresponding changeset, but no log was issued for this command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the command described in the title reversible?

no, if you `--clean`, you'll lose all changes in working directory

> I tried searching the log ... but no log was issued for this command

`hg up` **does not affect repository in any way**, it's a pure workdir command